# What is the user "representing" in an Outlook invite

Tags: outlook, icalendar, msg, msgkit

In the MsgKit library to create a `.msg` invite, there is the Sender, the Recipient, and the `Representing`. Like the Sender, there is exactly 1 Representing. It is documented as:

> These properties are examples of the address properties for the
> messaging user who is being represented by the MsgKit.Receiving user.
> They must be set by the incoming transport provider, which is also
> responsible for authorization or verification of the delegate. If no
> messaging user is being represented, these properties should be set to
> the e-mail address contained in the PR_RECEIVED_BY_EMAIL_ADDRESS
> (PidTagReceivedByEmailAddress) property.

Any idea who/what this is?

Comment: Try to post such questions to the library developers instead https://github.com/Sicos1977/MsgKit .

Comment: @EugeneAstafiev unfortunately they don't have any way to post questions to them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The **PR_RECEIVED_BY_EMAIL_ADDRESS** property contains the email address for the messaging user who receives the message. In Exchange you can use the [MailItem.SentOnBehalfOfName](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.mailitem.sentonbehalfofname) property which allows setting the display name for the intended sender of the mail message.

When a client application sends a message on behalf of another client, it should set all the represented sender properties to the values for that client. A messaging user sending on its own behalf typically leaves the represented sender properties unset.

Answer (score 1):

On the MIME level, you have `From` and `Sender` headers. On the MAPI level, you have `PR_SENDER_xyz` and `PR_SENT_REPRESENING_xyz` properties.
In most cases, they are one and the same. They are different when one person sends on behalf of another person, e.g. a secretary sending a message/meeting request on behalf of the boss.

Comment: Eugene answered fir so I selected his answer (wish I could select both). So I gave yours an up vote. thanks